# Rundeck - HTTP Workflow Step API Token

Tags: api, post, token, rundeck

In Rundeck, I have a series of HTTP POST workflow steps.  Is there a way to persist the API token from the initial login step to the subsequent requests?  Can this be done with log filters somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use data values for that, and call it using `${data.MYDATAKEY}` for steps and`@data.MYDATAKEY@` for inline-scripts.

Here you have an example:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>f9b4b925-3078-4668-bdf5-79e25173a183</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>HiWorld</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <description>generate token step</description>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <plugins>
          <LogFilter type='key-value-data'>
            <config>
              <logData>true</logData>
              <regex>^(MYTOKEN)\s*=\s*(.+)$</regex>
            </config>
          </LogFilter>
        </plugins>
        <script><![CDATA[echo "MYTOKEN=12345"]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
      <command>
        <description>print token or use on any step</description>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[echo "the token is @data.MYTOKEN@"]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>f9b4b925-3078-4668-bdf5-79e25173a183</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

In this way, you can use the same API token defined as data option in your job definition. Check [this](https://youtu.be/ao2SvpspWl4?t=175) to know more about how to work.

UPDATE: I changed the job definition example, now generate a token (simulated) and use it later in any workflow step.